# What is the most elegant way of broadcasting std::string in MPI?

Tags: c++11, mpi

In my MPI program, I am currently broadcasting a `std::string` as following. The code works, but I cannot find a more elegant solution than this (neither in other SO questions). Is there a better way (without using Boost.MPI)? Especially the `const_cast` makes me nervous.

```
std::string line
// Variable line receives a value on mpiid == 0.

int line_size = line.size();
MPI_Bcast(&line_size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if (mpiid != 0)
    line.resize(line_size);
MPI_Bcast(const_cast<char*>(line.data()), line_size, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the max size of the string can be known at build time (vs run time) and is reasonable, then you might want to consider `MPI_Bcast`ing a fixed size string.

It is debatable whether this is more elegant or not, but i believe this is more efficient from a performance point of view. The rationale is that as long as the max size of the strings is reasonable, a single `MPI_Bcast()` with a few extra (and useless) bytes is more efficient than two `MPI_Bcast()` with just the right number of bytes

Comment: This is not in performance critical code, but in the initialization, in which an input file with settings is read on one process and broadcasted to the others. I prefer to not make the string size fixed.

Comment: In this case, the original code looks just fine to me and from the `MPI` point of view (i am really not a `C++` guy)